# How to delimit comma-separated data into new rows while keeping the same label from another column for each new entry?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large excel sheet that I need to delimit on the commas, formatted like the [this example excel sheet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdb1A.png). I need to have each data entry in column2 delimited on the comma, and made into a new row in the sheet, but have the label in column1 copied for each new entry. So, if row 1 in the example was delimited, I would then have 5 rows that say tag1, and the 5 separate pieces of data from column2.

Edit:
Clarification on what I mean

My sheet is currently formatted like this:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
----------------------------
tag1     | data1,data2,data3
tag2     | data4,data5,data6
```

And I am trying to make it go like this:

```
Column 1 | Column 2
-------------------
tag1     | data1
tag1     | data2
tag1     | data3
tag2     | data4
tag2     | data5
tag2     | data6
```

Comment: I'm unable to understand the relation between TAG & DATA,,, if U wanna to put 5 comma delimited values in each row, then please show us the TAG & DATA (source data) are they more than 5 for each TAG?

Comment: Hey @RajeshS, I edited the question to try and clarify what I meant, the data is currently many pieces of data in one cell separated by commas, I need to separate them into individual rows like shown in the code example.

Comment: Do you want to do this by formulas or by VBA macro?

Comment: Hi @ConnorCozens,, now check my post,, it solves the issue, I've suggested a MACRO since is the best possible as per my knowledge,, so please [Edit] you post and add new  **TAG** , `VBA` , makes the answer more relevant . ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rather simple approach avoiding formulas/VBA alltogether. All you need is access to `Power Query`, build-in feature for most recent Excel but available as download for Excel-2010.

---

<sub>***Sample Data***</sub>

[image]

---

<sub>***Steps***</sub>

- Select all data
- Go to `Data` tab (or `Power Query` when it's a plug-in) and select `From Table`. Confirm that your data has headers.
- A new tab will open. But select "Column2" and click on `Split Column` (either on the `Start` tab or `Transform`. Choose to split on **delimiter**!
- In the next menu, to me the standard delimiter is a comma. Change it if need be. Then hit `Advanced` and choose to split into **rows**.
- Hit `OK`.

---

- Additionaly for cleaning purposes, right click "Column2" header > `Transform` > `Trim`.
- and exit `Power Query`, choose to **save** any changes.

---

<sub>***Result***</sub>

[image]

Comment: Hi @JvdV it's an amazing idea,,, was in my mind too but I've not posted since in general users avoiding Powe Query & BI as well DAX,,, and such initiatives sometimes attracts down vote,, like some one down voted mine ,, may not happy with VBA !!

Comment: hi  @JvdV I always welcome the good one,, so if you feel that the suggested code can be improvised than please post a new answer ,, help me lot to learn more and to the community also. ☺

Comment: Hey this worked perfectly, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score -1):

*What you are trying is looking possible by using Macro (VBA code).*

[image]

---

```
Sub SplitColumnToRow()

Dim objRegex As Object
Dim X
Dim Y
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim tempArr() As String
Dim strArr

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegex.Pattern = "^\s+(.+?)$"


X = Range([A3], Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
ReDim Y(1 To 2, 1 To 1000)

For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)

    tempArr = Split(X(lngRow, 2), ",")
    For Each strArr In tempArr
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 1

        If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve Y(1 To 2, 1 To lngCnt + 1000)
        Y(1, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 1)
        Y(2, lngCnt) = objRegex.Replace(strArr, "$1")
    Next
Next lngRow

[C3].Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y)

End Sub
```

---

**How it works:**

- To open VBA editor either press **Alt+F11** or **R**ight click Sheet `TAB`.
- Now hit **V**iew Code.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this code.
- **S**ave **W**orkbook as **M**acro Enabled.
- Finally **R**UN the Macro.

**N.B.**

- In this code `Range([A3], Cells(Rows.Count, "B")`, and  `[C3].Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2`, cell reference are editable.

*You may adjust them as your need.*

Comment: Gentleman ,, write your concern that why this has been down voted,,, !!

Comment: @JvdV,,, what has been used with the code are relevant to  use and are working nicely,,, if you find the easiest VBA code please add one will help me & others too,, I've used VBA and mentioned at TOP that is the possible method rather than formula and suggesting something new should be welcomed,, as I've mentioned that U tried Power Query,,, since is not a popular practice !!

Comment: @JvdV,, what I found suitable I've picked and composed the code,,, and I found are good enough,, since U have underlined the mistake so principally U have to put something new and try to justify your opinion !!

Comment: @JvdV,, since it matches specific patterns for the text so that is good to use as precaution to avoid the mistakes,, and there are many methods to solve the issue,,, I've picked both as fool proof sequence,,, and above all are working  !!